# PageViewer white borders on top and bottom

Tags: android, layout

My image is not adapting the screen completely. Is getting with white borders at the top and bottom
My images have 700x1002.

Please can someone help me get these edges and make the image/container fully fit the screen?

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearActions" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tourImageViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearActions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/tour_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnIdentify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonColorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGoHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonColorBlue"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeCircle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearActions"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@null" >

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/tourImageIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:fillColor="#027CC3"
            app:pageColor="#CCCCCC" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    int imageArray[];

    public MyAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArray) {
        imageArray = imgArray;
        activity = act;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        view.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

     @Override
     public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
      ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
      return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change your `view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);` to `view.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

Answer (score 0):

Its little bit late but none of the solution stated above did not work for me. So thought of sharing my solution which perfectly works.
If we set the ScaleType and Params in view(ImageView) then we might face problems either with LinerLayout/RelativeLayout.
So just set the ScaleType of ImageView something like below in viewpagerAdapter layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/sampleImage"
    android:id="@+id/img_pager_item"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    />
```